# LINQ Sum for given range of dates data

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Given a data with list of a months worth of data, I need to calculate the sum for past 2 weeks. I could do this by breaking the list in 14 days and then 7 days and calculate the sum for each.

Is there an elegant way to achieve above?

example of data list looks like below:

```
startDate 2012-05-01
value 1

startDate 2012-05-02
value 1
........

startDate 2012-05-31
value 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want the sum for *each* of the past two weeks, or a single value *across* the past two weeks? The latter is easier than the former:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Today;
// Note: inclusive at both ends, so this gives us 14 days in total
DateTime start = end.AddDays(-13);
var sum = data.Where(x => x.StartDate >= start && x.StartDate <= end)
              .Sum(x => x.Value);
```

Note that it's important to evaluate `DateTime.Today` *once* here, as otherwise if the query executes "around" midnight you could end up with an inconsistent set of comparisons.

If your data doesn't include any future values, you can remove the `end` part of course. You should also carefully consider whether you really want to subtract 13 days or 14.

EDIT: Okay, now you've clarified the requirement, it sounds like the *simplest* approach would actually be to execute two queries - one for the past 7 days, and one for the 7 days before that. Alternatively, you could use do it via grouping:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Today;
// Note: inclusive at both ends, so this gives us 14 days in total
DateTime start = end.AddDays(-13);
var sum = data.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
              .Where(x => x.StartDate >= start && x.StartDate <= end)
              .GroupBy(x => ((int) (end - x.StartDate).TotalDays) / 7)
              .Select(g => new { Start = g.First().StartDate,
                                 Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Value) });
```

Comment: I'm after each for past 2 weeks

Comment: @nilpun: See my edit. Although these will be weeks in the sense of "7 days before today" rather than always being (say) "Sunday to Saturday" weeks.